# Can not create a new RDS MySQL DB instance with parameter "lower_case_table_names=1"

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I have change lower_case_table_names in Parameter [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW1Mc.png)
But I modify database instance I can see the following error:
"The parameter value for lower_case_table_names can't be changed for MySQL 8.0 DB instances."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox44z.png)
Anyone has gone through this?

Please help.

Problem about Amazon RDS database

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not create a new RDS MySQL DB instance with "lower\_case\_table\_names=1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55544132/can-not-create-a-new-rds-mysql-db-instance-with-lower-case-table-names-1)